# Does my creature get stunned after killing Pip Pip with a Red Planet Ray Gun?

Tags: keyforge

I equip a creature with a [Red Planet Ray Gun](https://keyforge-compendium.com/cards/211-red-planet-ray-gun):

> This creature gains, “Reap: Choose a creature. Deal 1 damage to that creature for each Mars creature in play.”

Afterwards I reap with that creature and kill the only [Pip Pip](https://keyforge-compendium.com/sets/2-aoa/cards/116-pip-pip) in play. Pip Pip has the following effect:

> After an enemy creature reaps, stun it.

I would assume, that the effect of Pip Pip doesn't trigger, because Pip Pip dies **during** reaping, and the effect would only trigger **after** reaping. But I am not sure about the ruling. Does my reaping creature get stunned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The active Player chooses

Do you want your creature to be stunned? If there are multiple abilities that trigger after the reap, the active player chooses the order to resolve them in. So, if there was some reason you wanted your reaping creature to be stunned, you could resolve Pip Pip first, then the Ray gun. If you didn't want to be stunned, you could resolve the Ray Gun first, killing Pip Pip before it's ability could be applied.

Comment: But is it even possible to trigger Pip Pip anymore? Red Planet Ray Gun is a reap ability and Pip Pip - according to the card text - triggers AFTER reaping. Can you point me to the ruling where the exact sequence is explained? Is there something like a "reap phase" and a "after reap phase"? Based on your explanation, those two theoretical phases would happen at the same time. Don't get me wrong, I wouldn't rule that out - that's why I asked. But an official ruling would be great for reference.

Comment: "When a player uses a creature to reap, the player exhausts the creature, gains 1 Æmber for their Æmber pool, and then all “Reap:” abilities on the creature resolve." After you Reap any "Reap:" abilities resolve. Pip Pip ALSO resolve after a creature reaps. You could just as easily replace "Reap:" with "After this creature Reaps," if that helps make it make more sense to you.

Comment: It's worth noting that the rules are very explicit about BEFORE <keyword>: but noticeably lacking when it comes to AFTER <keyword> however resolution can be safely inferred from reciprocity.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the clarification! I accepted the answer and I know how to resolve this situation the next time.